# PHP Loggin System Session

Tags: php, html, session, authentication

So I'm new to PHP and atm i try to code a simple LogIn System. I set up a Sign up Site and linked it with the sql server. In the log in file i got this if statement.

```
    if  (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "Your username or Pw is incorect!";

} else {
      $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
}
```

I did test this (i put a 'echo' tag in the else part and it worked.  )

so on my index page i got this

```
<?php
if  (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
  echo $_SESSION['id'];
}else {
  echo "ur not logged in";
}
 ?>
```

This should give me the User id, but nothing comes out. Anyone spottet a mistake i made ?

Comment: you did start the session, *right?*

Comment: `<? php

session_start();

 ?>
` this is right or ?

Comment: that is indeed correct, minus the space between `<?` and `php` ;-)

Comment: Oh damm. Thanks mate :)

Comment: you're most welcome, *cheers*